# $S(p(t))=7p'(t)-2p(0)$. Is $S$ continuous in polynomial space under max-norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $\mathcal P[0,2]$ be the normed space of all polynomials on $[0,2]$ with norm given by
$$\|p\|_\infty=\max_{t\in[0,2]}|p(t)|$$
Define $S:\mathcal P[0,2]\to\mathcal P[0,2]$ to be an operator given by $S(p(t))=7p'(t)-2p(0)$. is $S$ continuous on $\mathcal P[0,2]$?

I have already shown that $S$ is a linear operator.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: also please create meaningfull titles in the future :) Mathstack isn't a forum, it is a platform to exchange mathematical problems.

Comment: Oh thanks, i tried to attach a picture but it was not so good

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not continuous, as e.g. the bounded sequence $p_n(x)= (x/2)^n$ is mapped to an unbounded sequence.

Comment: How to prove this by the definition of boundedness

Comment: Compute $\Vert p_n \Vert_\infty$ and $\Vert S( p_n )\Vert_\infty$ and show that the first one is always $\le 1$ whereas the second one goes to infinity as $n\rightarrow \infty$.